# Laravel 4 - Spaces in key fields breaking belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-4, space

I am setting up the following many-to-many relationship in Laravel 4:

```
class SampleType extends Eloquent {

  public function intake() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Intake', 'tbl_samples', 'Sample Type', 'Animal ID');
  }

}
```

However, when I echo out `SampleType::find(2)->intake;`, I get the following MySQL error because of the spaces in the 'Sample Type' and 'Animal ID'.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tbl_samples.Animal' in 'field list' (SQL: select `tbl_intake`.*, `tbl_samples`.`Sample` as `as`, `tbl_samples`.`Animal` as `as` from `tbl_intake` inner join `tbl_samples` on `tbl_intake`.`Animal ID` = `tbl_samples`.`Animal ID` where `tbl_samples`.`Sample Type` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 2, ))

Weirdly, the keys work fine on the WHERE and ON sections, but break on the SELECT part, where they seem to trigger AS aliases.

If I replace the spaces with underscores, it works fine, but I'd prefer to use spaces since the column names are echoed out on the front-end. Any way to keep my spaces intact, or do I need to use underscores in the models and switch them out later? Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to report. Building on this, how do those rows come back to you after being processed by PDO? `echo $result->sample_type`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `SampleType::find(2)->intake;` is what I was attempting. And I actually found that using underscores in the names of the relationship functions would also break things. I've had to use camelcase.

Comment: I see what you were asking now. I actually never asked for the columns specifically from Eloquent, I just shot everything toArray() since I had a ton of columns that I wanted spit out on the front end. Taylor confirmed that he has no idea what fun things will happen if spaces are put into column names. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [talked to Taylor](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2400) about it. He made a good point in that having column names with spaces doesn't work with Eloquent, since you wouldn't be able to access the field on the Model via $result->field. No spaces for me after all! Will switch to underscores and switch them out before I echo the column titles to the front end.